# Pagination Partial wanting to use with multiple controllers, models and views

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have created a partial for my pagination and want to use it for multiple pages like for an example a site that has a blog section and an e-comm section. I can get this to work for the most part the only thing that I can't figure out is having this work for multiple views that have different ViewModels and Controllers. Currently I have that hardcoded with the controllers and actions.

**_pagination.cshtml**

```
@model CTA_Client.Models.BasePageableModel


@if (Model.PageSize > 0 )
{
    <div class="center-block text-center">
        <ul class="pagination mb-lg-0 mb-5">
            <li class="page-item page-prev @(Model.HasPreviousPage == false ? "disabled" : "")" asp-route-PageNumber="@(Model.PageNumber - 1)">
                <a class="page-link" tabindex="-1" asp-controller="Blog" asp-action="List" asp-route-PageNumber="@(Model.PageNumber - 1)">Prev</a>
            </li>
            @for (int i = 1; i <= Model.PageSize; i++)
            {                   
                <li class="page-item @(@i == @Model.PageNumber ? "active" : "")">
                    <a class="page-link" asp-controller="Blog" asp-action="List" asp-route-PageNumber="@i">@i</a>
                </li>
            }       
            <li class="page-item page-next">
                <a class="page-link" asp-controller="Blog" asp-action="List" asp-route-PageNumber="@(Model.PageNumber + 1)">Next</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
}
```

**Blog.cshtml**

```
            ... 
            </div>
            @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_pagination.cshtml", Model.PagingFilteringContext)
        </div>
        <!--/lists-->
```

I created a `<ModelNameHere>ListModel` for each controller/Model that I will be using in the parent ViewModel. Here is the the `BlogListViewModel` one.
**BlogPagingFilteringModel.cs**

```
public class BlogPostListModel : BaseEntityModel
{
    public BlogPostListModel()
    {
        PagingFilteringContext = new BlogPagingFilteringModel();
        BlogPosts = new List<BlogPostModel>(); 
    }

    public BlogPagingFilteringModel PagingFilteringContext { get; set; }
    public IList<BlogPostModel> BlogPosts { get; set; }
}
```

You can see where I get the `PagingFilteringContext` that I pass from the parent View to the partial, this gives me the current paging values needed. I just need to be able to make the `<a></a>` tags dynamic in a way that I can use this in multiple views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are operating in the same page, for example, `/Home/Blog` to `/Home/Blog`, you can use `ViewContext.RouteData.Values` to get the corresponding controller and action:

```
<a class="page-link" asp-controller="@ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"]" asp-action="@ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Action"]" asp-route-PageNumber="@i">@i</a>
```

Html is displayed as

[image]

If you call a controller and action that is not currently executing, you can include `PageNumber, Controler, Action, etc.` attributes in a Model and pass them to the partial view.

For example:
Models:

```
public class BlogPostModel
{ 
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class BaseModel
{
    public int? PageNumber { get; set; }
    public int PageCount { get; set; }
    public bool HasPreviousPage { get; set; }
    public bool HasNextPage { get; set; }
    public string Controller { get; set; }
    public string Action { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Blog(int? pageNumber = 1)
{
    var blogs = _context.BlogPostModel;
    int pageSize = 3;

    var BaseModel = new BaseModel()
    { 
            PageNumber = pageNumber,
            PageCount = (int)Math.Ceiling(blogs.Count() / (double)pageSize),
            HasPreviousPage = pageNumber > 1 ? true : false,
            HasNextPage = pageNumber < (int)Math.Ceiling(blogs.Count() / (double)pageSize) ? true : false,
            Controller = "Home",
            Action = "Blog"
    };

    ViewData["BaseModel"] = BaseModel;
    return View(await PaginatedList<BlogPostModel>.CreateAsync(blogs.AsNoTracking(), pageNumber ?? 1, pageSize));
}
```

PaginatedList(refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/sort-filter-page?view=aspnetcore-7.0#add-paging-to-students-index)):

```
public class PaginatedList<T> : List<T>
{
    public int PageIndex { get; private set; }
    public int TotalPages { get; private set; }

    public PaginatedList(List<T> items, int count, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
    {
        PageIndex = pageIndex;
        TotalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling(count / (double)pageSize);

        this.AddRange(items);
    }

    public bool HasPreviousPage => PageIndex > 1;

    public bool HasNextPage => PageIndex < TotalPages;

    public static async Task<PaginatedList<T>> CreateAsync(IQueryable<T> source, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
    {
        var count = await source.CountAsync();
        var items = await source.Skip((pageIndex - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToListAsync();
        return new PaginatedList<T>(items, count, pageIndex, pageSize);
    }
}
```

Blog.cshtml:

```
@model PaginatedList<TestApp.Models.BlogPostModel>
//...
<div>
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_pagination.cshtml", ViewData["BaseModel"])
</div>
```

_pagination.cshtml:

```
@model TestApp.Models.BaseModel

@if (Model.PageCount > 0)
{
    <div class="center-block text-center">
        <ul class="pagination mb-lg-0 mb-5">
            <li class="page-item page-prev @(Model.HasPreviousPage == false ? "disabled" : "")" asp-route-PageNumber="@(Model.PageNumber - 1)">
                <a class="page-link" tabindex="-1" asp-controller="@Model.Controller" asp-action="@Model.Action" asp-route-PageNumber="@(Model.PageNumber - 1)">Prev</a>
            </li>
            @for (int i = 1; i <= Model.PageCount; i++)
            {
                <li class="page-item @(@i == @Model.PageNumber ? "active" : "")">
                    <a class="page-link" asp-controller="@Model.Controller" asp-action="@Model.Action" asp-route-PageNumber="@i">@i</a>
                </li>
            }
            <li class="page-item page-next @(Model.HasNextPage == false ? "disabled" : "")">
                <a class="page-link" asp-controller="@Model.Controller" asp-action="@Model.Action" asp-route-PageNumber="@(Model.PageNumber + 1)">Next</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
}
```